# What is the criterion for a change to be adiabatic?

Tags: classical-mechanics, adiabatic

I'm trying to understand whether the change of a parameter $\lambda$ of a Hamiltonian $H$ is adiabatic. Reading Landau and Lifshitz "Mechanics", I see

> ... let us suppose that $\lambda$ varies slowly (adiabatically) with time as the result of some external action; by a "slow" variation we mean one in which $\lambda$ varies only slightly during the period $T$ of the motion:
>   $$T\frac{d\lambda}{dt}\ll\lambda.$$

But we can choose $\lambda$ in such a way that it has arbitrarily large value by taking Hamiltonian as $H'(\lambda)=H(\lambda-C)$, where $C=\mathrm{const}$ is a large compensating constant. Thus the condition of adiabaticity would be automatically fulfilled for arbitrarily fast change.

Reading [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_invariant), I see

> In mechanics, an adiabatic change is a slow deformation of the Hamiltonian, where the fractional rate of change of the energy is much slower than the orbital frequency.

But again, we can shift energy by arbitrarily large constant without affecting the equations of motion, and then any change of energy will have very small logarithmic derivative.

Thus the criteria given above are too ambiguous to be usable.

So, what is the true unambiguous criterion for the change to be adiabatic? Or, if the criteria cited above are unambiguous, then what is my mistake?

Comment: Maybe, you should take a concrete situation. For example, a pendulum whose length is slowly reduced. You could define the mean energy, the parameter slowly variable and confirm (or not) that there is an ambiguity ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question and the answer is... we don't really know.

The adiabatic theorem can be stated in various forms. A rigorous one is the following. Assume the Hamiltonian changes in time only as a function of $t/T$, where $T$ is a timescale (total evolution time). Under a gap and other regularity conditions, if you start in an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian at time zero and evolve up to a time $t<T$ the adiabatic error is

$$
\frac{C}{T}.
$$

Where $C$ is a constant independent of $T$. Your question asks for a precise estimate of the constant $C$. This can be obtained in various ways, a rigorous estimate is provided in [this paper]( 
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0603175)
by Jansen and Ruskai and Sailer. But this expression is not optimal and an optimal expression is not known. There is an "estimate" that is referred to in standard undergrad textbook which is usually called naiive condition. It is known not to be necessary actually but it provides a good order of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

Look to the more fundamental, classical definition. Adiabatic just means 'without heat transfer'. But more specifically it requires defining a system or control volume where the heat is not transferred.

Your model or equations of motion must exist over some defined space and time interval. If heat is not transferred in/out of the system, the process is adiabatic.

Comment: Erm... in the framework of pure classical mechanics, not thermodynamics, what is heat?

Comment: Heat is one of the many ways energy expresses its presence. Waves are another way.

Comment: So, in your answer heat is energy. But in adiabatic change of parameter the energy may not conserve, that's the point of _external change_ of parameter. So your criterion seems too restrictive.

Comment: I didn't say heat **is** energy. Rather heat is a way energy expresses its presence. Fundamentally we don't really know what energy **is**. All we know is its something that's conserved. Feynman stated that in his published Lectures - volume 1.

Comment: Well, could you then express the criterion in more explicit non-thermodynamic terms? I still don't get what relation I have to check to definitely say whether my system changes adiabatically or not.

Comment: (1)Define a control volume in space that contains your system, or those parts of your system that you are interested in. (2)Monitor the boundaries of the control volume(s) for any heat flux. (3)Zero flux over the time monitored tells the system is adiabatic

Comment: How do I define heat flux for a single particle?

Comment: @Ruslan That's a good question, but one I can't answer. 'Flux' I believe deals with a macroscopic examination of a system of particles. When it comes to a single particle I suppose you could call it flux. A particle leaving the system, and carrying energy with it would constitute heat loss.

Comment: @Ruslan I have to admit I'm not well versed with quantum mechanics, so it may be that 'adiabatic' may carry a different meaning than used in classical mechanics. In considering control volumes, the subject of coarse graining comes to mind and how its used to determine entropy of a system. Roger Penrose gives a good description in his 'Road to Reality', section 27.3. This might also help answer your question.